# React onEnded event not firing on mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, video

I have a React component with an HTML5 Video tag. The `onEnded` event gets fired on the desktop resolutions but failed to do so on the mobile browser. (Including Chrome DevTools mobile emulator)

```js
<video 
  data-vjs-player 
  video-id={videoId} 
  data-account={BRIGHTCOVE_ACCOUNT} 
  data-player={ARTICLE_PLAYER_ID}
  controls 
  autoPlay 
  onEnded={() => console.log('Ended...')} 
/>
```

Comment: Can you specify browsers and OS of the mobile devices where this doesn't work?

Comment: I'm testing on Chrome with mobile mode on DevTools on